# Android: HTTP communication should use "Accept-Encoding: gzip"

Tags: android, http, gzip, content-encoding

I've a HTTP communication to a webserver requesting JSON data. I'd like compress this data stream with `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Is there a way I can set `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in my HttpClient? The search for `gzip` in the Android References doesn't show up anything related to HTTP, as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=gzip&t=0).

Comment: [Android-WebRequest](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-WebRequest) supports GZIP and uncompressed responses automatically, e.g. with `new WebRequest().get().to("http://www.example.com/").askForGzip(true).executeSync()`. Specifically, the method [parseResponse(...)](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-WebRequest/blob/master/src/im/delight/android/webrequest/WebRequest.java) should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You should use http headers to indicate a connection can accept gzip encoded data, e.g:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
// ...
httpClient.execute(request);
```

Check response for content encoding:

```
InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
}
```

Comment: That is a great and very helpful answer with all the details I needed. Thanks a lot.
One comment: instead of addHeader I used setHeader. From what I understand this overwrites the existing "Accept-Encoding" if there is one. Not sure which approach is the right/better one. To overwrite an existing header to make sure it has the right value, or to add it in case that there can be other Accept-Encoding headers in parallel.

Comment: where do you put the instream  then?

Comment: this does not gzip the request, it only tells the server that you can accept a gzip'd response.

Comment: For anyone also having trouble to get this up and running for google services here are two issues which took me quite some time to find out:
(1) some google services require the user agent string provided by the client to contain the string `gzip` to _really_ enable gzip compression.
(2) keep in mind that the server may not gzip the response if it is too small...

Comment: My problem is that the gzip header is nowhere to be seen. I am using Wireshark to sniff the network on the server side, and I see no trace of the "gzip" header that I added in android...

Comment: @znq Android itself uses `addHeader(...)` in `AndroidHttpClient`'s method `modifyRequestToAcceptGzipResponse(...)` so you should probably use that.

Answer (score 33):

If you're using API level 8 or above there's [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html).

It has helper methods like:

```
public static InputStream getUngzippedContent (HttpEntity entity)
```

and

```
public static void modifyRequestToAcceptGzipResponse (HttpRequest request)
```

leading to much more succinct code:

```
AndroidHttpClient.modifyRequestToAcceptGzipResponse( request );
HttpResponse response = client.execute( request );
InputStream inputStream = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent( response.getEntity() );
```

Comment: Nice tip the modifyRequest & getUngzipped, also, I needed to copy EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity) to parse the ungzipeed stream as String

Comment: AndroidHttpClient was deprecated in API level 22.

Answer (score 13):

I think the sample of code at this link is more interesting:
[ClientGZipContentCompression.java](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhc.apache.org%2Fhttpcomponents-client-ga%2Fhttpclient%2Fexamples%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fhttp%2Fexamples%2Fclient%2FClientGZipContentCompression.java&rct=j&q=HttpClient%20Accept-Encoding%20header&ei=VyYqTsT4LYP2swPhjMXCCg&usg=AFQjCNHn8noW2I7vOSjfIAVOg_DzjS6Cww&sig2=ZYD8ZP0VvblTSd1vBQDAAw&cad=rja)

They are using **HttpRequestInterceptor** and **HttpResponseInterceptor**

Sample for request:

```
        httpclient.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {

            public void process(
                    final HttpRequest request,
                    final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                if (!request.containsHeader("Accept-Encoding")) {
                    request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
                }
            }

        });
```

Sample for answer:

```
        httpclient.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {

            public void process(
                    final HttpResponse response,
                    final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Header ceheader = entity.getContentEncoding();
                if (ceheader != null) {
                    HeaderElement[] codecs = ceheader.getElements();
                    for (int i = 0; i < codecs.length; i++) {
                        if (codecs[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                            response.setEntity(
                                    new GzipDecompressingEntity(response.getEntity()));
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Any reason why you think it is more interesting?

Comment: @codingcrow Here's what you're looking for : _In this particular case HTTP client is made capable of transparent content GZIP compression by adding two protocol interceptors: a request interceptor that adds 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' header to all outgoing requests and a response interceptor that automatically expands compressed response entities by wrapping them with a uncompressing decorator class. The use of protocol interceptors makes content compression completely transparent to the consumer of the HttpClient interface._

Comment: [Source](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientGZipContentCompression.java)

Comment: GzipDecompressingEntity can't be found in android.jar (2.2)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used GZip, but I would assume that you should use the input stream from your `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpResponse` as `GZIPInputStream`, and not some specific other class.

Comment: HTTPURLConnection has gzip turned on by default. You just need to make sure your web server can return gzip pages.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

I was able to return gzip pages from php by using ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

Comment: Don't answer when you don't have an answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was like this:

```
URLConnection conn = ...;
InputStream instream = conn.getInputStream();
String encodingHeader = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding");
if (encodingHeader != null && encodingHeader.toLowerCase().contains("gzip"))
{
    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
}
```