# Android webview ,how to show Http response?

Tags: android

How to show response in webview?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mymobilece.com/api/api_getexammaterials.php?id=27");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println("Respnce body :: " + responseBody);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
String line = "";
String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
    }
bufferedReader.close();

Toast.makeText(View_Materials_Activity.this, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

String webData = stringBuffer.toString();
String webData1 = URLDecoder.decode(webData);
System.out.println("data :; " + webData1);
webView.loadData(webData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.ilias.de/docu/", webData,"text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");
```

Responce body ::

```
    ýb>&ª4+ü"ðÐôí{Á>
            Ó~5xGåYxôùuo_xÆ¾Ô­§¶·:7<5áË]SK×¤ÿ��^ Ï|ÿ��si÷ú©­þÏî|9â©,u¿ê±x+ámö§¨kW?4¸ÔE¼>){íTÑ|Cá{-SÄ^Õ´ý+Ç~Õ¼'w6¯¡Ú.+ [ðã§üãâ-¶ºÚìá¦ø"ÖÏá÷>+êñøá¿Ã­#IÃÚF¥üWñ
            ¼ºâSÂñê7?Ä[_Ï¢êZ¥1_Qiü¿ìÍpé Gìéû`þÇ÷Þ:ðÿ��þ|×<«|GÔí<    ·¤xoáôíAü9­ê|òÁã¨µKëOIñ/L¾N¶Ónu;ujþÒu{
            Äv?üàü%±xCLðÅO\Ïñg_ø+±á­A×ôãíOÛ&6¡¥ø¢èÚ[jÚ¼3¥Ø_]Ã¼zÆ£m¨½hz¹´��ð_~Û?°¤(ñ    ðwÀ;­KVñ&¥©x+ÄÖái¦xRøªøÏÄz
            ö§ãë;
            \xÿ��ì¾3Öåá¤Ò|A}¨
            ûBó_ñ.¤ßr¾%øßûüøýã_º§ìð÷Â^ð:õ¯é'Ã;»[Ãþð×Å5}2ïQÒeÁÚì_õË[=SV¸å¼Eý¨5K4ÐuYõ6ü=ñçö?õZoì¡¦Ùü/o|?¶Ðt¿^îæ×IýücûBÜøÿ��Â]°¶Ó´oü<ñ×Åm:&¾×EÞ«®izsiâ¸ìÿ��µ¯ì?áÝOZðÝ¿ìÉ«C®|bÑ¼'¢x×NÓ¼ð¢óþO\é®{©ê67Jø¦Yi~Õ<]âØôâOÚè¾xÛþØ?°Gü%àßZþËlzçf·Ñ|5
            §>èÑëº¤øuâ~h<Ï_j:Gôý2_    éz­-íô-/J¸GobäMøïûÅ¯|CÔ.gOVñ£ûB|Bñ§ü
```

Comment: What part of the response do you want? The HTTP Status? HTTP Headers? HTML?...

Comment: HTML that show in webview....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, an HTTP response is not HTML. It's HTTP. It might contain HTML. Use [`HttpResponse.getEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity%28%29) and then [`Entity.getContent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29) and you can read the data (presumably HTML) from the stream. Then you can use [`WebView.loadData`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to load that data.

**Update:**
Your data might also be gzipped... Take a look at this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573391/android-http-communication-should-use-accept-encoding-gzip) for more details.

Comment: +1, What you mean by final solution. my dear user has already given the final steps for the "Final solution". Try it by yourself first.

Comment: @Paresh i print responseBody.But it cant display in webview? So you have solution to display it in Webview and how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5263/discussion-between-samir-and-paresh-mayani)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5264/discussion-between-samir-and-paresh-mayani)