# Android, how to load 'gz' file from URL and automatically decompress content on load?

Tags: android, http, gzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: HTTP communication should use “Accept-Encoding: gzip”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573391/android-http-communication-should-use-accept-encoding-gzip)

My Android application downloads `temp.bin` file but today it (file) too big. I configured Apache to  compress it to `temp.bin.gz` by using `gzip`. So i got 10% from actual size.

So far so good. Now the problem is how to decompress it in Android side during downloading.

I used before this snippets of download algorithm:

```
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);

        // set redirect mode ...        
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
        connection.setReadTimeout(0);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

        connection.connect();  

                    ....

InputStream in = null;
        //boolean lengthValid = (contentLength != -1); 

        byte    bytes[] = new byte[256];
        int     total_count = 0;
        int     max_count = 0;

        try {
            in = connection.getInputStream();
            int count = 0;


            while (count != -1){
                count = in.read(bytes);
  ....
```

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a [GZIPInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) to wrap your stream? Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1576513/967142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` instead of `InputStream`

[Also See](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html)