# Any workaround for Android Webview to handle compressed data?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working with an android app which renders part of a mobile site in `webview` component. `Mobile site` sends compressed data to client so behavior is quite good when accessed through regular mobile browsers however since webview doesn't honour compressed data, UI wasn't so good.

Are there workarounds to handle this?

[EDIT]: server adds gzip in the header of the HttpResponse. Webview doesn't honour the gzip header.

I found a solution on SO ([Android: HTTP communication should use "Accept-Encoding: gzip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573391/android-http-communication-should-use-accept-encoding-gzip)). Haven't tried it out but yet to find a more elegant solution. Also wondering it's a `webview` which is equivalent to a browser but why it's not equally powerful.

Comment: Is that Gzipped content not properly interpreted by a Webview?

Comment: Please specify *exactly* what you mean by "compressed data".